# Tableau reshaping a row with origin/destination into two separate origin and destination rows

Tags: pivot, tableau-api, reshape

I am trying to turn data that looks like this:

```
DeparturePort   DepartureLatitude   DepartureLongitude  ArrivalPort    ArrivalLatitude  ArrivalLongitude  Data
ABERDEEN        46.983              -123.817            BURNTISLAND    56.0500          -3.233            100
ABERDEEN        46.983              -123.817            CROMARTY       57.6833          -4.033            200
ABERDEEN        46.983              -123.817            IMMINGHAM      53.6333          -0.200            300
```

Into something that looks like this: (to eventually plot path lines on a map)

```
Port         Latitude   Longitude   Type         Path                   Data
ABERDEEN     46.983     -123.817    Departure    ABERDEEN-BURNTISLAND   100
BURNTISLAND  56.0500    -3.233      Arrival      ABERDEEN-BURNTISLAND   100
ABERDEEN     46.983     -123.817    Departure    ABERDEEN-CROMARTY      200
CROMARTY     57.6833    -4.033      Arrival      ABERDEEN-CROMARTY      200
ABERDEEN     46.983     -123.817    Departure    ABERDEEN-IMMINGHAM     300
IMMINGHAM    53.6333    -0.200      Arrival      ABERDEEN-IMMINGHAM     300
```

I've tried using a pivots but it never seems to look very close to what I want. Is there another type of reshaping I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use **UNION ALL** to effectively combine 2 copies of the table back to back -- turning each original data row into two rows.

And then to create one latitude field drawing from the original DepartureLatitude field on the first row, and the ArrivalLatitude on the second row. (Similarly for Longitude), and add a new Type field to distinguish Arrival Rows from Departure rows.

You can either use the Tableau Union feature in the data connection pane, and calculated fields to create the new coordinate fields. Or custom Sql along the lines of

```
select port, departure_latitude as latitude, "departure" as type from x
union all
select port, arrival_latitude as latitude, "arrival" as type from x
```